# how can i show two tables in single view in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How can I use multiple models in a single view page in an MVC application?

Comment: Tip: do not use Entity Framework entity types as View-Models. Instead define a custom class for the view which includes the entities objects as properties.

Comment: Another reason not to use Entity Framework entity types as raw View-Models is because ASP.NET will blindly bind data, so a malicious user could overwrite your email address if they know your UserId by doing `POST Email = 'foo@bar.com'&UserId=(your user-id)`.

Comment: What plaform are you using? WPF, Asp.net, Xamarin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewModel` exists for the exact reason you mention. Its primary purpose is to service the View. Its the place where you mix up multiple models and provide the View with a single data structure

Imagine you have below models:

```
public class A { }

public class B { }
```

You should create a `ViewModel` Class like below code:

```
public class ABViewModel 
{
   public A A {get;set;}
   public B B {get;set;}
}
```

then update your view accepted model:

```
@model ABViewModel
```

And finally, you should pass this `ViewModel` to your view. good luck